I can't the load js on Odoo17
I try to upgrade modules from Odoo 14 to Odoo 7, but when I try to do upgrade. I have an issue with JS. I can't load JS, even if I define the path in manifest.
I need Help.
We have a custom JavaScript module in Odoo that is responsible for handling notifications via a bus service and displaying them in a dialog. This setup was functioning correctly in Odoo 14, but is now encountering issues after migrating to Odoo 17.
Problem Description:

The JavaScript module does not seem to load or function as expected in
Odoo 17. We suspect there might be changes in how Odoo 17 handles
JavaScript modules and their dependencies.
odoo.define('announcements.NotificationManager', function (require) {
"use strict";

// Require necessary dependencies
var AbstractService = require('web.AbstractService');
var core = require('web.core');
var Dialog = require('web.Dialog');
var rpc = require('web.rpc');

// Define a new service called SHNotificationManager that extends AbstractService
var SHNotificationManager = AbstractService.extend({
    dependencies: ['bus_service'], // Declare dependency on bus_service

    /**
     * @override
     * Start the service and register a listener for notifications
     */
    start: function () {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments); // Call the parent start method
        this.call('bus_service', 'onNotification', this, this._onNotification); // Register notification listener
    },

    /**
     * Callback function for handling incoming notifications
     * @param {Array} notifs - Array of notifications
     */
    _onNotification: function (notifs) {
        var self = this;
        _.each(notifs, function (notif) {
            var options = {
                model: notif[0][1], // Notification model name
                type: notif[1].type, // Notification type
                title: notif[1].title || 'Notification', // Notification title (default if null)
                message: notif[1].message || 'No message', // Notification message (default if null)
                id: notif[1].id, // Notification record ID
            };

            // Check if the notification is for the res.partner model and has the 'announcements_dialog' type
            if (options.model === 'res.partner' && options.type === 'announcements_dialog') {
                self._showDialog(options); // Show the dialog with the notification details
            }
        });
    },

    /**
     * Show a dialog with the notification details
     * @param {Object} options - Notification options
     */
    _showDialog: function (options) {
        var dialog = new Dialog(this, {
            title: options.title, // Dialog title
            message: options.message, // Dialog message
            size: 'medium', // Dialog size
            $content: $('<div>').html(options.message), // Dialog content
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Close',
                classes: 'btn-primary',
                close: true,
            }],
        });

        dialog.on('closed', this, function () {
            rpc.query({
                model: 'user.notify',
                method: 'close_notify',
                args: [options.id],
            });
        });
        dialog.open(); // Open the dialog
    },
});

// Register the SHNotificationManager service with the core service registry
core.serviceRegistry.add('announcements_notification_service', SHNotificationManager);

// Return the SHNotificationManager service
return SHNotificationManager;

});

Have you looked into Odoo 17 JS Framework? Odoo Owl framework was introduced not that long ago. Some features where migrated completely to Owl some others have new and legacy code. I'm not sure if the bus service has legacy code anymore, something you should look up.
